# Virtual Hosts in Apache Tomcat 6 and above

Tags: tomcat

I'm trying to set up virtual hosts for Apache Tomcat 6 in a Windows Environment. My goal is to have the url 'm.test' to point to a custom landing page.

I have changed my **hosts** file to have 'm.test' point to '127.0.0.1'

In my **tomcat_root/conf/server.xml** file, I've added the following entry:

```
<Host name="m.test" appbase="webapps\test_webapps" autodeploy="true" unpackwars="true" xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
```

where **test_webapps** is placed under my **tomcat_root/web_apps** folder.

When I navigate to to *m.test:8080*, I see the default tomcat file, not the index file in **webapps\test_webapps**.

In my tomcat console, after I log into the 'Tomcat Manager," **INFO: HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'm.test'** and (blank).

Could anyone know what the reason for this is?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the reason it doesn't work is that you have specified appbase rather than appBase. Case matters.

Second, don't nest the appBase for one host under the appBase for another. I'd suggest using appBase="webapps-m.test" for the m.test host.